# Can I force Doctrine 2 repository to check entityManager for results first

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, persistence

I expected that Doctrine 2 repository would check the `EntityManager` for results first. But it doesn't.

This code represents the issue.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$firstName = 'Michael';
$lastName = 'Jordan';
$userEntity = new User($firstName, $lastName);

$em->persist($userEntity);

$userRepository = $em->getRepository('UserRepository');

$expectingMichaelJordanUserEntity = $userRepository->findOneBy(array('firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName));
```

In this example the `$expectingMichaelJordanUserEntity` is `null` because the entity has not been saved to the database. Shouldn't it look inside the entity manager for persisted entities first?

Is that the meaning or is there a way to get my example to return the persisted `User` entity?

Comment: Why do you need to do a database request for an entity that you recently created instead of just using it directly?

Comment: You would have to flush the entity manager before doing the findOneBy.  The entity manager just maintains a big list of entities indexed by id.  It does not try to emulate a full blown in memory database.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this, was because I'm parsing and importing a big junk of data, which is done in one flow. In that junk of data I may need to auto create some Users out of the data I receive. While the users are the owners of the rest of the data. And I need to check many times in the import process, if the user exists. There are of course many way to solve my problem...

Comment: ... But for the speed, clarity and simplicity of the code, it would have been create to just persist the user, without flushing, that I created and then continue doing the rest of the import, until it is time to check for the user again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking doctrine to `findOneBy` those criteria inside the database. In your case it returns null but it could as well return a record if there would be such a user `firstName = 'Michael' AND lastName = 'Jordan'` inside your database.

The result of this `query` has nothing to do with your newly created user.

If it would return the user from the `EntityManager` then you would not know whether it is from the database or from memory.

Comment: In my particular case it wouldn't matter, if it is in the database or in the entity manager. So for the speed in mind it would be smart to check what is available in the entity manager first.